# use value of wildcard in other parameter

Tags: linux, wildcard

Is there a one line solution for this?

I have many files and subdirectories in a directory.
For a simplification lets say I have only

```
./dir1/file1
./dir2/file2
./file3
```

I want to run a command for each of this files using wildcard (*) and then use the value of the wildcard to generate ID of a file in format dir_file and put it as another parameter of a command

e.g., for

```
command -file * -id <something>
```

in the case of 3 files from the example this should be called after expanding the wildcard:

```
command -file ./dir1/file1 -id dir1_file1
command -file ./dir2/file2 -id dir2_file2
command -file file3 -id file3
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in `Bash` it is not possible because:

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans
>   each word for the characters *, ?, and [. If one of these characters
>   appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an
>   alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern.

That means that a single `*` would be replaced with a list of all files that match the pattern. Try it yourself - after typing `*` in your terminal press M-S-* (that means hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> together) and wildcard will be expanded.

You can achieve what you want using `find`, it can however get unreadable pretty quickly:

```
find . -type f -name "*"  -exec bash -c 'command -file {} -id (echo {} | sed -e 's,\.,dot,' | sed -e 's,/,_,g' )'  \;
```